# Monitor switches to secondary display when I turn off my TV

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

- Monitor connected to my DVI port, and my TV connected to my stereo (HDMI) which is connected to my HDMI port on my computer.
- Monitor is set as primary display.
- Same behavior when I set the monitors to dual or extended.
- Video card is ATI Radeon HD 5700 series.
- Using Windows 7 (64-bit)

When I turn off my tv, the monitor will flash off, then on (auto-detect?). After it comes back it only has the background and mouse cursor on it (is now the secondary display?). I have not been able to open any windows in it, they all get displayed on the primary display (which should be the monitor).

More strangeness:

- turn off stereo then turn off TV, monitor does not change (still primary display)
- switch receiver input from computer to other HDMI, turn off TV, monitor is broken (secondary display?)

Ok, so I think I figured out why turning off the stereo stops my computer from resetting the monitor. Turning off the stereo cuts the communication between the TV and the computer, so the TV can't tell the computer "Hey, I turned off, switch the monitor."

I still need some way to disable this communication permanently.

Also, after turning the stereo and TV back on I cannot play sound to the TV. It doesn't appear in the mixer menu or devices in Windows Media Player.